# How to Refactor this jQuery Fade in effect?

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I'm new to writing jQuery and wanted to get some help on how refactor something.. I'm trying to get elements to fade in sequentially on the page load. The effect works well, but it looks clumsy in the code. Can someone with more experience help me refactor this to be more efficient?

```
$('.home h1').delay(100).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow');

$('.home h2').delay(250).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow') ;

$('.home h3').delay(400).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow');

$('.home hr').delay(550).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow');

$('.homeimages > img').delay(900).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow');


$('.homenav').delay(1000).animate({
    opacity : '1'
}, 'slow');
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read about chaining in jQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SrikanthAD I don't see how chaining could be used here any more than it's already used.

Comment: Is there a more consistent naming pattern that you may be able to use, so you can just iterate over the elements with `$('.home .selector').each(function(i,ele){})`; and perform the animation in the `$.each()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

```
var elements: {
    'selector': 100, // delay
    'selector2': 200 // delay
};

for( var selector in elements ) {
    $(selector).delay( elements[selector] ).animate({
        opacity : '1'
    }, 'slow');
}
```